# ExtJS setting a textareafield setValue()

Tags: javascript, extjs

Im learning Extjs and have a problem , when i try to append new text to an item i get an error **tf.setValue is not a function**  same goes for `getValue`. When i try `setVisible` it works like it should be.

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled:true});

Ext.application({
    name: 'app',
    controllers:[
  ],
    appFolder: 'app',
    launch: function() {
        var panel = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
          renderTo:Ext.getBody(),
          title:'Panel',
          width:400,
          bodyPadding: 10,
          autoHeight:true,
          items:[{
            xtype:'textareafield',
            name: 'textInput',
            id:'textId',
            value:'why not'
          },{
            xtype:'button',
            text:'Helllo',
            handler:function(){
              console.log('button click')
              var tf = Ext.get('textId');
                    tf.setValue('This should change!')
            }
          }],
        });
    }
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `Ext.get()` will return an `Ext.Element`.

What you want to use is `Ext.getCmp('textId')` which will return the component.

The Element is basically the Ext wrapper round the Dom element, so it has methods like setVisible, but you want to get the text area component, which has all the methods you're after.